# Difference between: new ExampleConstructor and Object.create(ExampleConstructor)

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, javascript-objects

Code as attached

```
function Bird() {
  let weight = 15;
  this.getWeight = () => weight
}

// let birb = new Bird
let birb = Object.create(Bird.prototype);

console.log(birb.getWeight())
```

When I use new Bird it returns a function fine. However, when I use Object.create(Bird.prototype), I get a TypeError telling me birb.getWeight is not a function.

Why does creation from the prototype interfere with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getWeight` doesn't exist on the prototype. It is created on the object itself when the constructor function is run (which isn't happening when you use `Object.create` instead of calling the function).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So in this case there's no way for me to use Closure within the Object and use Object.create at the same time?

Comment: @andrewjosephus — Correct. The `Bird` function isn't going anywhere near `Object.create`.